# create jquery extension. problems with scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a simple jQuery extension(it's my first).

```
(function($){
  var MyClass = function(opt){
     //..
  };
  //one of the methods of my extension
  $.fn.myExtension = function(opt){
    this._ext = new MyClass(opt);
    return this;
  };
  $.fn.myExtensionOtherMethod = function(){
    if(this._ext){
      //do something ..
    }
    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));

//using ..
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#selector').myExtension({
    //options ..
  });
  $('#selector').myExtensionOtherMethod();
});
```

when i invoke method `$('#selector').myExtensionOtherMethod();`, `this` does not contains `this._ext` variable. I know that this is other scope, but i know that there is some way to access that variable in both methods.how can i do it?

Comment: What is your end goal, are you wanting a new instance of myClass or options for each element that matches the selector, or a single instance of myClass that your extension will use no matter what element is selected?

Comment: You are creating a different object each time you use `$('#selector')`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Using `data()` will probably help

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a scope issue. This is because the jQuery prototype `$.fn` gives you a jquery object as `this`. Even though you are selecting the same element each time its a new jQuery object set as the context so that property is gone. You can put that property on the DOM element and achieve the outcome you want.

```
(function($) {
    var MyClass = function(opt) {};
    //one of the methods of my extension
    $.fn.myExtension = function(opt) {
        this[0]._ext = new MyClass(opt);
        return this;
    };
    $.fn.myExtensionOtherMethod = function() {
        if (this[0]._ext) {
            //do something ..
        }
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));

//using ..
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selector').myExtension({
        //options ..
    });
    $('#selector').myExtensionOtherMethod();
});
```

This is just a quick example above. If your selector finds more than one element you should loop though them. But I only grabbed the first index since you were selecting by ID.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/gd1ehk0d/

As mentioned above by @charlietfl, I agree with that comment. Happy to explain why what you did didn't work but there may be better ways to achieve what you are looking for.